# How to group file names in a directory using the file name extensions with python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to group files in a directory according to their extensions using a dictionary but my code is not behaving as expected. I have several video files ending with `.mp4`, I have a script that gets the extension of the file and then checks if it exists as a key in the dictionary.

**NB:**

`Dictionary holds extensions as keys and all the files with the extension as items`.

If extension exists as a key in the dictionary then it adds the current file name to the items associated with that key. If it does not exist then a new key entry is created in the dictionary with null items. My code is printing the elements of the dictionary like below

```
'.mp4': 'Edited_20220428_154134.mp4', '.png': 'folder_icon.png',
```

You can see from the above output that my code does has the extensions as keys but for the videos it only contains a single item when there are several videos in that folder, I need help to make it key the extensions and add all the file names with that extension to the items associated with that key.
Below is my code

```
#import the os module
import os
# define the path to the documents folder
path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents"
# list all the files in the directory
files = os.listdir(path)
# sort the files lexicographically
files.sort()
# code to ask user to choose file operation, in this context user chooses group by extension
# code omitted for MRE purposes
print("Grouping the files by extension")
# initialize the dictionary for holding the extension names
extensions = {}
# iterate through each file name and split the name to get file name and extension as a tuple
for file in files:
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext not in extensions.keys():  # if the key extension does not exist add the key to the dict as a new entry
       extensions[ext] = file
    else:  # if the extension already append the item to the key items
        extensions[ext] = file
#print the dict to check if the operation was succesful
print(extensions)
```

Comment: Just realized I need to iterate through the dict a second time to add the items

Comment: What do you mean second time? IMO the only problem is that you're using `=` when you should be using `.append()`

Comment: It should be`extensions[ext].append(file)` when the key already exists.

Comment: Okay trying that out, Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: What if the key does not exist in the dictionary, How do I add a new key entry and initialize items to null?

Comment: for `extensions[ext.append(file)` am getting this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in files:
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext not in extensions.keys():  
        extensions[ext] = [file]
    else:
        extensions[ext].append(file)
```

You're overwriting all of your files if the extension is found with `extensions[ext] = file`. the `=` is setting that dictionary item to the value of one singular file.

In my code above, you create a list the first time the extension is found. And every time after that you add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
if ext not in extensions.keys():
   extensions[ext] = file
else:  # if the extension already append the item to the key items
    extensions[ext] = file
```

you are overwritig and not appending the value in the dictionary.
Try to use:

```
if ext not in extensions.keys():
   extensions[ext] = file
else:  # if the extension already append the item to the key items
    extensions[ext] += [file]
```

using the **+=** operator to append the desired file names.

Answer (score -1):

try this if you want to group file names that are similar in a directory

```
    import glob
    x=glob.glob(_filepath_)

    dictionary={}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).